# Get valid orders at the starting day of each year

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

In a table containing *Order* information (call it **Order**) we have the following fields:

1. **OrderId** int
2. **OrderDate** Date
3. **BindingTime** int

Binding time is in months.

An order is called "Active" between its `OrderDate` and `DATEADD(mm, BindingTime, OrderDate)`.

What I'd like to do is to group the orders by year so that if an order is "active" on the first day of a year it would be taken into account. The aim is to calculate each year's inbound and outbound orders. So the query result will be `COUNT` of orders and the year. And by year we mean the number of orders which were active on the first day of that year.

Mind that, we would like to have all the years between two given numbers in our results. E.g. If there was no active order on the first day of 2016 we would still like to to have a row for (0, 2016).

Comment: you know the drill... sample data and expected output please

Comment: are you wanting to count ONLY orders active on the first day of the year, or orders that are active at some time in the year?  In the second case, are they counted twice if they span the year start?

Comment: @Cato ONLY the ones that are active on the first day of the year. Being active is an interval. So if that interval includes first of January of a year, it should be taken into account. If an active order spans multiple years, it should include all the years in which the first day is inside that interval.

Comment: that's what I've done below hopefully

Answer (score 1):

I've used a recursive CTE to generate a range of years, so that a 'zero' year will not be omitted

```
declare @YEAR1 as date = '20110101';
declare @YEAR2 as date = '20190101';

WITH YEARS AS (SELECT @YEAR1 y
               UNION ALL
               SELECT dateadd(year,1,y) FROM YEARS WHERE y < @YEAR2)
    SELECT YEARS.y,count(0) YearStartActiveOrders FROM YourTable 
         CROSS JOIN YEARS 
       WHERE YEARS.y BETWEEN CAST(orderdate as date) 
                 AND CAST(DATEADD(mm, BindingTime, OrderDate) as date)
                      GROUP BY Years.y
```

Comment: Let me check the results and come back to you. Looks correct.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like what you need is a Date table (having a list of all days per year) and left joining that table with your grouped data (active order count, per day of the year).

You can use [this date table from Aaron Bertrand](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server). I generated the #dim table with the following params, to only generate two years data (2015, 2016):

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATE = '20150101', @NumberOfYears INT = 2;
```

Then you can do the following:

```
with ordertable as
(
 select 1 as orderid, '20160101' as orderdate, 2 as bindingtime union all
 select 2, '20160305', 3 union all
 select 3, '20160305', 5 union all
 select 4, '20150305', 5
)
select d.year, isnull(count(orderid), 0) nrActiveOrdersFirstDayOfYear
from #dim d 
     left join ordertable g on d.year = year(g.orderdate) 
                               and g.orderdate = d.date 
                               and d.FirstOfYear between g.orderdate and DATEADD(mm, g.bindingtime, OrderDate)
group by d.year
```

With the sample data I took as an example, you would get the result:

```
year    nrActiveOrdersFirstDayOfYear
2015    0
2016    1
```

Working demo [here](http://rextester.com/CUGL5421).